# EF Code First , using Git in Team mode, using SqlServer (Merging migration is having confusion)

Tags: git, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

**User One**
Migration 11-1-2016 One
Migration 13-1-2016 Two (Both are commited)

**User Two** (Now this user want to commit)
Migration 11-1-2016 Three
Migration 12-1-2016 Four

To my knowledge migration works based on time.

I am having trouble updating database.

Do anybody know how to use migrations in this situation.

Comment: Looks like an old question that was edited, but this will depend on whether each user has their own database or a shared one. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx) for dealing with migrations in team environments.